# Opening pop up in Joomla

Tags: joomla, popup, window, new-operator

I am trying to have people be able to open HTML widgets by clicking on a button in my Joomla page. All the widgets are different sizes. The code is entered as HTML in Jumi. Currently I have the action set to:

"On click open in new window without browser navigation."

The problem is this this always opens in a full screen size with the widget showing up in a corner.

How do I control the size of this new window for each widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a code sample of how you're calling the new window, or the URL?

If you're using `target="_blank"` you're not forwarding any container information for the new window (which sounds like the behavior you're describing).

There are many *lightbox* / *slimbox* options available for download from [The Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), which could help address this for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should search the JED for modal windows. Modal windows will do exactly what you want without you having to do any coding or workarounds. They're also much neater.